# openpose installation error - Errors detected. Exiting script. The software might have not been successfully installed

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, ubuntu

I really need to know what's just going on here.
I'm trying to install openpose, and I went through a whole pre-installatio process - installing CUDA, cuDNN, ATLAS, and Opencv.
But I still experience the error as following and don't get it built properly yet.
It says there's no "ubuntu/Makefile.config.Ubuntu16_cuda8.example" found, but I do have a file called the exact same, so don't know why it shows like this.
I've been struggling against it for hours, really need some help.
Thanks in advance.

*thing has changed after a while so I edited my previous question.

------------------------- Compiling OpenPose -------------------------
cp: cannot stat 'ubuntu/Makefile.config.Ubuntu16_cuda8.example': No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.

Comment: Can you try installing `numpy` first? `pip install numpy`

Comment: thank, but ive alreay got numpy with my python, and can import it in python without any problem. it's in dist-packages. do i need to add any path for openpose to reach it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy `ubuntu/Makefile.config.Ubuntu16_cuda8.example` as `Makefile.config` (in the main OpenPose folder, not inside the ubuntu folder), then call `make all -j8` from the main folder.